# Joda-Time new DateTime() vs DateTime.now()

Tags: java, jodatime

Since Joda-Time time version 2.0 the static method `org.joda.time.DateTime#now()` was introduced.
To me it is not clear what is the benefit over the use of `new DateTime()` (as the code just delegates anyway).

```
public static DateTime now() {
    return new DateTime();
}
```

Also from the java doc it is not clear to me which one I should prefer.

```
new DateTime
```

> Obtains a {@code DateTime} set to the current system millisecond time using `ISOChronology` in the default time zone.

```
DateTime#now()
```

> Constructs an instance set to the current system millisecond time using `ISOChronology` in the default time zone.

Can someone explain in which use case which one should be preferred?

Comment: Since they do the same it doesn't really matter, for me `now()` makes it clearer what I get back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`new DateTime()` requires that a new object be allocated. `DateTime.now` can reuse a single object across requests, since [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) instances are immutable. That may cause less memory churn.

But largely I doubt it matters which you use.

Answer (score 3):

The `now()` method was added to make Joda-Time a little bit closer to `java.time.*` in Java 8, making the process of conversion a little bit easier. The two methods have exactly the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any difference. Using DateTime.now() looks more elegant than new DateTime() in your code. Here is DateTime.now() source code.

```
public static DateTime now() {
    return new DateTime();
}
```

Comment: Always go to the source! :)